# How to create this UI effect for UITableView? (image included)

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, swift

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AYVg.png

I'd like to know how the background of the tableview and the section header are created so that it all appears as one fluid view. As you can see there are no extra blank rows and the section header and background of the tableview are the same color. And how is the word "ALERTS" created? It's very close to the row, so is that a custom uilabel?

I've managed to create something similar by creating a zero rect for the footer of the uitableview and have set the color so that it matches the section header, however, when the view loads there is some lag and its very noticeable that the background color is being changed.

Comment: It's a grouped style table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the tableView, you need to make its style UITableViewStyleGrouped.

For example:

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```